# ¿Cómo generar una tabla con input mediante uso de laravel y ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, ajax

Estoy realizando una tabla que se genera al dar click en un boton tomando el valor de un input mediante jquery y enviarlo al controller con ajax

Controller

```
public function tabla(Request $request){

    if($request->ajax()){
    $orden=$request->get('orden');

    $pagos=DB::table('hoja_trabajo as ht')
    ->join('servicio_reparacion as sr','ht.servicio_reparacion','=','sr.clave')
    ->join('catalogo_servicio as cs','sr.clave','=','sr.servicio')
    ->select('ht.no_orden','cs.clave_servicio','cs.precio','cs.tipo')
    ->where('no_orden','=',$orden)
    ->get();
    dd($pagos);
     foreach($pagos as $pa)
   {
    $output .= '
    <tr>
     <td>'.$pa->no_orden.'</td>
       </tr>
    ';
   }

   $data = array(
        'table_data'  => $output            
    );

    echo json_encode($data);    

    }
```

jquery y ajax

```
        <script>
            $(document).on('ready',function(){

          $('#generar').click(function(){
         var orden = document.getElementById("orden_servicio").value//obtener valor del input


 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ route('notaPagocontroller.agregar')}}",
    data:{_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",orden:orden},
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data.table_data);
    $("#table-body").html(data.table_data);
    }
  });
  alert(orden);
    return false;
        });
       });
     </script>
```

En mi blade solo tengo una tabla con sus th respectivos, mi ruta es un post
Route::post('nota.create','NotaPagoController@tabla')->name('notaPagocontroller.agregar');

no se que este haciendo mal, no me da error la consulta,  gracias

Comment: Probaste la consulta directamente en la base de datos? Tienes un dd() después del get, me imagino que lo pusiste en la pregunta por error? Como consejo, te recomiendo no enviar la tabla desde el controlador, es mejor enviar los datos unidamente, y crear el html cuando recibes la respuesta del ajax

Comment: si funciona la consulta y la probe, que podria estar mal?

Comment: Que te retorna el ```console.log(data.table_data)``` en el success del ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, yo tengo un código parecido.

Lo que necesitas hacer es declarar $Output de la siguiente manera

```
    foreach($pagos as $pa)
   {
    $output[] ="<tr><td>".$pa->no_orden."</td></tr>";
   }
```

Y no sera necesario que coloques esta parte

```
$data = array(
        'table_data'  => $output            
    );
```

Así la variable que vas a retornar es $output